# Web flow and access/refresh tokens via php

Tags: visual-workflow, oauth2, php, web

I'm trying to implement a web flow authentication process using php; so far, I've created the necessary index.php file which is used to get the first code:

```
// Generate a random code verifier
$codeVerifier = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(random_bytes(32)), '+/', '-_'), '=');

// Create code challenge from the verifier using SHA-256
$codeChallenge = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(hash('sha256', $codeVerifier, true)), '+/', '-_'), '=');

// Set your Salesforce OAuth parameters
$clientId = $CLIENT_ID;
$redirectUri = 'https://mydomain.dev/redirect.php';
$scope = 'api';

// Construct the authorization URL with PKCE parameters
$authorizationUrl = sprintf(
    'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&scope=%s&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=%s',
    $clientId,
    urlencode($redirectUri),
    urlencode($scope),
    $codeChallenge
);

header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
exit;
```

The above code goes to salesforce, and back to my site and the redirect.php page with the code as a parameter; a code which I will use to retrieve the access/refresh tokens.

The redirect.php is the following:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'code' => $_GET["code"],
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => $CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret' => $CLIENT_SECRET,
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://mydomain.dev/redirect.php',
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($response, true) . "</pre>";
```

Theoretically, at the end, I should end up with a json object containing both access and refresh tokens.

Instead, I'm ending up with the following error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid code verifier"}
```

PS: I am not interested in a simple username/password authentication, because I want to store both access/refresh tokens for a server side process.

Can you help me guys, to understand what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client is your friend

Comment: Hello @identigral, I have to admit that I'm not very familiar with oauth2; I haven't found a proper example easy to understand. Perhaps I'll give it a try, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a `code_challenge` in your token request, you must include a `code_verifier` parameter when requesting the access and refresh tokens. Either (a) do not use `code_challenge`, or (b) make sure you specify the same value that was in the `code_challenge` parameter from the first token request. You can read more about the parameters in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5). If you want to use the code challenge, you can store the randomly generated code in a PHP session value in step 1, then use it in step 2.